# Read data as list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

```
     x       y
[133,28,23] female
[157,22,87] male
[160,33,77] male
[122,87,20] female
[120,22,20] female
```

This is the data that i have in my book.csv file.

```
>>fd=pandas.read_csv("C://users/admin/Desktop/Book1.csv")
>>l1=[h for h in fd.x]
```

After following commands, `l1` stores this value:

```
['[133,28,23]', '[157,22,87]', '[160,33,77]', '[122,87,20]', '[120,22,20]']
```

The following output is string in list format, but i want nested list like this:

```
[[133,28,23],[157,22,87],[160,33,77],[122,87,20],[120,22,20]]
```

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: data.x.tolist()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: still the same                                                                                                
 >>> fd.x.tolist() 
['[133,28,23]', '[157,22,87]', '[160,33,77]', '[122,87,20]', '[120,22,20]']

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following, using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

data = [['[133,28,23]', 'female'],
        ['[157,22,87]', 'male'],
        ['[160,33,77]', 'male'],
        ['[122,87,20]', 'female'],
        ['[120,22,20]', 'female']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['x', 'y'])
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
result = df['x'].tolist()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[133, 28, 23], [157, 22, 87], [160, 33, 77], [122, 87, 20], [120, 22, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json:

```
>> import json
>> fd=pandas.read_csv("C://users/admin/Desktop/Book1.csv")
>> l1=[json.loads(h) for h in fd.x]
[[133,28,23],[157,22,87],[160,33,77],[122,87,20],[120,22,20]]
```

Or ast

```
>> import ast
>> fd=pandas.read_csv("C://users/admin/Desktop/Book1.csv")
>> l1=[ast.literal_eval(h) for h in fd.x]
>> [[133,28,23],[157,22,87],[160,33,77],[122,87,20],[120,22,20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way, if you don't want to resort to `ast` (for example to avoid parsing something that is not a list):

```
from io import StringIO

inp = """     x       y
[133,28,23] female
[157,22,87] male
[160,33,77] male
[122,87,20] female
[120,22,20] female"""

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(inp), delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
# Remove brackets, split and convert to int
df.x = df.x.map(lambda el: list(map(int, el.strip()[1:-1].split(','))))
# Print
l1 = [h for h in df.x]
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[[133, 28, 23], [157, 22, 87], [160, 33, 77], [122, 87, 20], [120, 22, 20]]
```